# I want full 1920x1080 to my projector but laptop is 1330

Tags: projector, 1080p

I want full 1920x1080 res since the projector allows for it. But laptop limited to 1330 or so. Mac book pro 2012 model. Will the thunderbolt to hdmi allow for full 1080 to the projector?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the external graphical capabilites are dependent on the graphics card / connection and not the internal display of your laptop. You can check the specs of your laptop on the [apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp649).

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors